# Неправильно устанавливается время GregorianCalendar

Tags: java, android, calendar

Инициализирую календарь:

```
Calendar startDateTimeCalendar=new GregorianCalendar();
```

Смотрю в отладчик, я так понимаю сейчас в календаре лежит текущее время и дата, вот что написано в отладчике:

> Fri Sep 21 14:27:41 EET 2018

Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы время стало на начало дня:

```
startDateTimeCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR,0);
startDateTimeCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
startDateTimeCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
startDateTimeCalendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);
```

Но почему-то время ставится вот такое:

> Fri Sep 21 12:00:00 EET 2018

Если сделать конец дня, вот так:

```
startDateTimeCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR,23);
startDateTimeCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,59);
startDateTimeCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,59);
startDateTimeCalendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,999);
```

То в отладчике видно, что в календаре теперь уже не конец дня, а вот какая дата:

> Sat Sep 22 11:59:59 EET 2018

Почему так? Как исправить, чтобы устанавливалось начало дня и конец дня?

Answer (score 3):

Решился вопрос, оказывается нужно было использовать другую константу для установки часов, именно **HOUR_OF_DAY**.

Вот правильный пример:

```
startDateTimeCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,23);
startDateTimeCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,59);
startDateTimeCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,59);
startDateTimeCalendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,999);
```

Comment: Доп.инфа из справки: ``HOUR`` используется для 12-часового режима, ``HOUR_OF_DAY`` для 24-часового.